# Creating a contract in Remix, not working

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

I am fairly new to solidity programming and using the Remix IDE to run and compile my Smart Contracts.For some reason whenever I open remix.ethereum.org website on Firefox the browser crashes.
Currently using it in IE. This is the simple code i am trying to run.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;
contract sample{

    string name;
    uint age;

    function setName(string newName) {
        name=newName;
    }

    function getName()returns (string) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

But after clicking on Create button under the Run tab I dont see any textbox to enter Name or getName.
**creation of sample pending...** This is the message i get on the console.
[image]

Comment: Same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

The code works fine for me. Try it in Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you have this problem using a **Google Chrome** browser...

**Open a new browser tab, then open remix.ethereum.org**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a browser issue. Please check the details by clicking the button in the console, there should be a contractAddress if succesfully created. try copy-pasting that into "Load contract from address" and click at address.

I use both chrome and firefox with remix (chrome on windows, firefox on ubuntu) and never had any issues. Try clearing browser cache and the like or try updating browser.

Answer (score 0):

I´m also fairly new to Solidity. I tried the previous steps (changing browser, loading contract) but none of them worked.

I only found that even though the transaction says it´s pending, if you check the details you would see the information correctly. **I´m assuming the contract is working.**

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

Try using a lower version of the compiler, it works.